# Origin of crawled properties in sharepoint 2013

Tags: search, web-application, managed-property, crawled-property

Our search service crawls several web applications (both SharePoint and external sites).

Thus, our Search Schema lists a lot of crawled (and managed) properties.

Is it possible to find whether a particular crawled property (say "Property_X") was generated after crawling which web application ? I can't seem to find this option anywhere...

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I have never been able to track this down. When it matters I have tracked the "before and after" state of crawled properties by enumerating them with PowerShell. I never have found a way to do it after the fact. Sorry.

Comment: I'm amazed if that is really the case! I'm not in charge of the server and search setup, but I'm responsible for setting up Search Query Webparts. But seeing as there are more than 1,200 Managed Properties as it is right now, I really need to clean them up.